# My user id doesn't work in a query

Tags: support, data-explorer

This is my profile link:
https://data.stackexchange.com/users/26755/taz

My understanding is my user id is 26755.

But when I run this query:

```
select * from users where id=26755
```

(at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new ) it gives me another user's information.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12):

26755 is your SEDE (data.stackexchange.com) user id.

Not your UserId on any other site.

For example, your user id here, on meta is 369766 (if you go to your account page here, you will see it in the URL).

You user id on Stack Overflow is 8560391.

Comment: OK, thank you. Then, if I run this query "select * from users where id=369766 " it should give me my information, but this query doesn't give any output. (run at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new )

Comment: "select * from users where id=8560391" doesn't give anything either.

Comment: Yes, your user was created 4 days ago. We only refresh SEDE once a week. Give it past the weekend.

Comment: From the FAQ/Help page on SEDE: `The last update was Sep 3 at 7:08.`

Comment: OK, got it now. So there is no problem with my query, it's just that the data needs to be updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Extending @Oded 's answer: If you have account on many sites, or if you want to *compare* things between different sites, it could be useful to use your network Account Id. It is visible in your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/11692652/taz): 11692652. So you have to note, or you have to use only a single number. It is in the `AccountId` column of the `Users` table, and this is the same on all sites.

Thus,

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE AccountId = 11692652
```

will be the same query on all the sites you've registered, and it will show your user data everywhere.